# How to resize the textview along with toolbar according to the content in objective c

Tags: ios7

I used the following code, but I couldnt get the result

```
CGRect newFrame = _text_view.frame;
CGRect newToolbarFrame = self.navigationController.toolbar.frame;
newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, fixedWidth), newSize.height);
```

From the above code please let me know what is newsize?

Comment: Provide more information like how you initialized newsize.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I initialized by CGRect and I am not sure in what I am doing is correct.The problem I faced is the textview is getting increased by height, the last line of the textview  hides by the keyboard.Can you please provide some code for increasing the textview as well as the tool bar by not hiding the keyboard.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For extending the height of textview upwards as per the content, I used [this](https://github.com/adonoho/HPGrowingTextView) gitHub project.

And for simply changing the location of text view so that it remains above keyboard, try this

```
// First add these
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

Then in these methods, do this

```
- (void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note {

    //Get keyboard size and loctaion
    CGRect keyboardBounds;
    [[note.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue: &keyboardBounds];

    // get a rect for the textView frame
    CGRect containerFrame = _text_view.frame;

    // Provided you keep fixed number of maximum lines
    containerFrame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.size.height - (keyboardBounds.size.height + containerFrame.size.height);

    // set views with new info
    _text_view.frame = containerFrame;

    // Change toolbar location as per it's height
    _tool.frame=CGRectMake(0, 
                           _text_view.frame.origin.y - _tool.frame.size.height, 
                           _tool.frame.size.width,
                           _tool.frame.size.height);

}

- (void) keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)note{

    CGRect keyboardBounds;
    [[note.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue: &keyboardBounds];

    // get a rect for the textView frame
    CGRect containerFrame = _text_view.frame;
    containerFrame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.size.height - containerFrame.size.height;

    // set views with new info
    _text_view.frame = containerFrame;

    // Similarly again change toolbar location
}
```

Or you can simply keep textview in scrollView and change the insets of scroll view when keyboard shows up.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Sorry I couldn't understand what you meant by keyboardbounds. I am currently using this code for changing the location of tool bar.

Comment: NSDictionary *keyboardInfo = [note userInfo];
 NSValue *keyboardFrameSize = [keyboardInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey];
 CGRect keyboardFrameBeginRect = [keyboardFrameSize CGRectValue];
_tool.frame=CGRectMake(0,420,_tool.frame.size.width,_tool.frame.size.height);
  [_text_view setFrame:CGRectMake(40,423,_tool.frame.size.width,120,_text_view.frame.size.height)];
 [_text_view setContentSize:CGSizeMake(_tool.frame.size.width,_tool.frame.size.heigh100)]; UIEdgeInsets insets =_text_view.contentInset;_text_view.contentInset = insets;
 text_view.scrollIndicatorInsets = insets;

Comment: I am also facing problems in, After three times the tool bar is not moving its location along with the keyboard.Please help me out.

Comment: keyboardbounds is same as keyboardFrameBeginRect which will give you keyboard's size.